# BubbleWrap CLI shows Error The given android-sdk isn't correct when bubblewrap build

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, twa, bubblewrap

I want to build `TWA` using BubbleWrap CLI

When I try to build my app using `bubblewrap build`

```
|  |) /_,--.,--|  |-.|  |-.|  |,---.,--.   ,--,--.--.,--,--.,---.
|  .-.  |  ||  | .-. | .-. |  | .-. |  |.'.|  |  .--' ,-.  | .-. |
|  '--' '  ''  | `-' | `-' |  \   --|   .'.   |  |  \ '-'  | '-' '
`------' `----' `---' `---'`--'`----'--'   '--`--'   `--`--|  |-'
                                                           `--'    
(node:1798) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental


cli ERROR The given androidSdk isn't correct.
```

It shows error `cli Eroor The given androidSdk isn't correct`

Here is my file structure is

```
- application
|
|- jdk
|- android-sdk
|- my-app
```

My `~/.bubblewrap/config.json` contains

```json
{
  "jdkPath":"~/application/jdk",
  "androidSdkPath":"~/application/andoid-sdk"
 }
```

My OS

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: I had downloaded https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-6609375_latest.zip android CLI tools.

Answer (score 2):

*Modify the folder of the android-sdk to look like this: android-sdk -> tools -> bin, lib

Optional Commands:

`bubblewrap updateConfig --androidSdkPath [your android-sdk path]`

run `bubblewrap doctor` to check all

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

I got Bubblewrap to work with the latest version of command-line tools downloaded from https://developer.android.com/studio. (currently 6858069)

The downloaded archive file will have a directory called cmdline-tools, this needs to be renamed tools and put inside the android-sdk directory.

Your directory structure should look like

```
./android-sdk/
./android-sdk/tools
./android-sdk/tools/bin
./android-sdk/tools/lib
```

Then Bubblewrap asks for android-sdk I used the absolute path to the android-sdk directory, instead of using the ~ (tilde) character. I do not believe ~ is supported by Bubblewrap, as it is a node application and node does not support ~ by default according to https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/684 . This should be true for your jdk path also.

Bubblewrap will continue and ask you to accept the licenses. After, it will start downloaded extra files to the android-sdk directory so read-write access is also needed.

Comment: Thanks, had the same error and had to create a folder: "tools", default name after extract was cmdline-tools

Answer (score 1):

to solve when you can not execute and you get the address error message. just duplicate and copy the `sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat` to `sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager`, in the same directory.